# Light Align tool ( LightPaint feature as in HDRI Light Studio )

Tags: light

Theres a way to click a face, edge or vertex and align a light

(just as in HDRI Light Studio native align light tool)?
(Thats how you align a light hovering an object surface):

Its called LightPaint.

https://gcs-vimeo.akamaized.net/exp=1510774932~acl=%2A%2F801377317.mp4%2A~hmac=e0f62e9b2fbae5529b6b69f7e225fe524825da41f6129eec1761bd7aad94f180/vimeo-prod-skyfire-std-us/01/548/9/227744549/801377317.mp4

Any similar feature in Blender?

Comment: Hi, please detail some more for people that maybe never used 3d studio max...what you mean by "align" to a vertex, edge or face? You could add images to explain how it works there... or a before/after in blender.

Comment: ok ill add more details to this.. thanks!

Comment: Blender Light Studio is a plugin which has a functionality like that: https://leomoon.com/downloads/plugins/blender-light-studio/

Comment: Yes, the nearest answer i had.. This feature helps me a lot when lighting a scene! Thanks a lot! :)

But i doesnt places a light where you "click". You still orientates light. You are still moving light. 

If you check the feature i posted (video) it shows the user hovering a mesh to place highlights.

Comment: I've added an answer that shows how to do it. The Add-on does have the functionality you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Add-on **Blender Light Studio** - https://leomoon.com/downloads/plugins/blender-light-studio/ - offers that functionality via a modal operator. Activate the Add-on and add a light profile in the Toolbar on the left. After that, add a light via the interface too. Now, when a light is active, you can enable the interactive placement mode, called **3D Edit**, like this:

[image: light editing]

Basically, you click on a face of the model, and the Add-on calculates the light position for you. Once you're happy, hit the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to exit the interactive placement mode.

Comment: Yes, worked as intended. Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: Now (year 2021), this addon "Light Studio" uses a shortcut. Just check in preferences, the "fast edit" shortcut option.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after seeing the video, here below you find a possible way: use a trackto constraint.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Its almost that. The point of that 3d max align light tool is that i dont need to "touch" lights. Just click where i need highlights for example.

Comment: I updated my question. Thanks for your feedback since from how i should ask till your answer. Im improving the way ill ask future questions, and answer other users needs. 
I just updated using another software, called HDRI light studio, where it shows a recording with my needs, using its feature called LightPaint. Thanks again.